# Reference for an inequality between $|x+y|^p$, $|x|^p$, $|y|^p$, and $|x-y|^p$

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

I am interested in an inequality for real numbers $x,y$ and $1<p<\infty$ that it should say something like
$$
|x+y|^p -|x|^p - |y|^p \leq (1-2^{1-p})|x-y|^p. 
$$

Is this inequality (or something similar) valid?

Where can I find a proof?

Comment: looks like a consequence of Jensen's inequality

Comment: This is not correct. Set $p = 2, x = y = 2$.

Comment: @Hans Engler: I am not sure about the true expression. Maybe there is something like $|x+y|^p- |x|^p- |y|^p\leq C |x-y|^p$.

Comment: No. Take $x=y$ to get $x^p(2^p-2) \leq 0$ which is generally false in that case too.

Comment: Looks similar to [Clarkson's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson%27s_inequalities).